# ClassCastException ExtractingRequestHandler while trying to index PDF in Solr

Tags: pdf, solr, solrj

I'm facing some difficulty indexing PDF in Solr. Initially I had a lot of JAR missing, which I included all (specially from "dist" and "contrib\extraction" folder. But now when I try to index my PDF I'm facing this ClassCastException ExtractingRequestHandler. Have anyone encountered this before or have any idea what's going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting solr-cell.jar in your classpath. ExtractingRequestHandler class is inside solr-cell jar file.

Put it under /webapp/lib folder followed by restart.

Comment: I did this already (...I included all (specially from "dist" and "contrib\extraction" folder...)

Comment: actually I couldn't find the exact problem and hence solution yet, but bypassed it by running the solr in jetty server that comes in package.

Comment: Its good you found the work around but just out of curiosity did you check whether you had solr-cell.jar in lib folder?